# How to add list of contacts to Lead object

Tags: apex, list

I have the following test method:

```
static testMethod void testLeadStatusExistingDeal() {
    Test.startTest();
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    contacts.add(contact);
    Lead record = new Lead(LastName = 'Dimitrov',Company ='emp1,Monthly_Volume__c= '1234', 
                            Phone='1423542452', Website='www.google.com');
    insert record;
    System.debug('record ' + record);
    ApexPages.StandardController c = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);
    LeadToMerchantController ltmc = new LeadToMerchantController(c);
    String leadStatusExistingDeal = ltmc.leadStatusExistingDeal(record);
    System.debug('leadStatusExistingDeal ' + leadStatusExistingDeal);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

In the Lead record `Lead record = new Lead(LastName = 'Dimitrov', Company ='emp1', Monthly_Volume__c= '1234', Phone='1423542452', Website='www.google.com');`
I would like to add a parameter list of contacts. 
Could you please advise how this can be achieved programmatically.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: `I would like to add a parameter list of contacts` what do you mean? you question is not clear to me?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to add a child list to contacts and that you have a relationship field present in contact(lookup or Master Detail. This can be achieved programmatically at the time of creating contact record not the lead record itself. Suppose the name of the field in contact that looks up to lead is "Lead__c".Then to insert a contact record that is the child of the leas=d record you have inserted now:

```
Contact testContact = new Contact(LastName='John Doe', Lead__c = record.id);
```

Now the above line creates a contact record which is a child of the lead record named 'record' i.e. which you have successfully inserted previously.

You create other contacts similarly, as long as the lookup/MD field to the parent is populated successfully they will be correctly assigned to that parent. I hope this is the list of contacts that you wanted to assign as a parameter to the lead record named 'record' that you have already created. Hope this helps and am sorry if my understanding was wrong and couldn't help.

Thanks